# When to Use <Space> component or <Row> and <Col> in Antd V.4?

Tags: reactjs, antd

When to use Space Component ? on the website it says

> "Avoid components clinging together and set a unified space."

if by that means, i can use Row and Col components too to achieve the same thing,

ex :
i have 3 button in same row (like the basic usage of Space Component on docs)

using Space =>

```css
<Space>
  <Button type="primary">Button1</Button>
  <Button type="primary">Button2</Button>
  <Button type="primary">Button3</Button>
</Space>
```

using Row and Col Component =>

```css
<Row gutter={8}>
  <Col span={8}> 
    <Button type="primary">Button 1 </Button>
  </Col>
  <Col span={8}> 
    <Button type="primary">Button 1 </Button>
  </Col>
  <Col span={8}> 
    <Button type="primary">Button 1 </Button>
  </Col>
</Row>
```

Thanks for everyone that helping this :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<Space>` and Grid components (`<Row>` and `<Col>`) are intended for different purposes.

`<Space>` is intended to be used in instances where you have a set of elements that need to be laid out inline and you want to have some spacing between them. Using the `<Space>` component with the different pre-defined `size` values bring a unified concept of spacing throughout your application.

Grid components are intended for addressing more complex layout requirements. While it is true that you can achieve the same outcome of `<Space>` component with Grid components, using Grid components for achieving spacing needs does not provide you with a unified concept of spacing throughout your application. And for the example you have given, it is basically an overkill to use the `<Row>` and `<Col>` components to just achieve spacing.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer, I see the concept now. :)

Comment: @truchranga Thanks for the explanation. Do you by any chance know how to achieve this using <Space />: Render a specific number of equal-spaced items in a single row when fetching data dynamically? For example, from an API, I am receiving a total of 8 items. The default property of <Space /> is that it'll render 8 items in equal space in a single row. But what if I want to render only 4 items only, not 8? How can we achieve this?